# javaspace(Apache river) cannot initialize outrigger script

Tags: apache, jini, javaspaces

I need to use jini (Apache river) to set up JavaSpaces service. The problem is I cannot start the space service script while the `net.jini.core.lookup.ServiceRegistrar` works well.

Here are the output I'm getting:

[image: Error]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It the missing class path that needs to be add to start up

set %apphome%=M:\river-apps\

%Javahome%\java -Djava.security.policy=%apphome%config\policy.all -jar %apphome%lib\start.jar %apphome%config\start-outrigger-group.config